# how to clear a jtextfield pushing a button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have a JButton and when I push it, it has to clear all the content in a JTextfield. How can I do this? Maybe there exists a method to clear a JTextfield or do I have to set the field to `null`?

Comment: what did you do to solve the requirement on your own? Seriously, this is simple a) reading of the api doc of JTextField b) reading a textbook/tutorial chapter on how to make buttons trigger something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`JTextField#setText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method should do it with an empty `String` as text.

As for reacting on the `JButton` click, attach an `ActionListener` to it. The Swing tutorials illustrate this all in great detail.

1. [Button tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
2. [Text component tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
3. [ActionListener tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: dag, beaten by 4 seconds! arg! 1+

Comment: And it seems those 4 seconds are worth a lot of reputation. Never gained so much on such a simple question ;-)

Comment: not much leeway for doing anything wrong in answering a simple question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`setText(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method with an empty string argument:

```
myTextField.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `setText("")` method of the `JTextField` class passing in an empty string as the parameter. This will replace what is in the `JTextField` with ""

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You could even extend the `JTextField` class and add a method called `clear()`. That class would look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomJTextField extends JTextField {

    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    public void clear() {
        setText(EMPTY_STRING);
    }
}
```